# cant i use `set ANSI_NULLS OFF

Tags: t-sql

in stored procedure cant i set `set ANSI_NULLS OFF`  instead of using  `(first_name IS NULL)` in one of my query...
also i want to know how can i debug stored procedure and how can i see result generated by stored procedure ...like for normal query i get the option  `sql` written tag.......but how can i achieve this for stored procedure....please elaborate me on this too

basically i want to know, following is my exact query

```
SELECT     student_id, first_name, last_name, user_name, password, father_name, DOB, gender, local_address, permanent_Address, phone, mobile, email, college_id, 
                      course_id, branch_id, highschool_passout_year, highschool_percentage, ssc_passout_year, ssc_percentage, passing_year_higher, graduation_percentage, 
                      graduation_passout_year, post_graduation_percentage, post_graduation_passout_year, diploma_percentage, diploma_passout_year, number_of_ATKT, 
                      current_backlog, gapin_education, sem1P, sem2P, sem3P, sem4P, sem5P, sem6P, sem7P, sem8P, total_sem_percentage, total_year_percentage, flag, image, 
                      native_place, high_school_board, ssc_board, diploma_university, graduation_university, post_graduation_university, training_details, Project_Work, Skills, 
                      extra_curricular, blood_group, profile_updated, year_of_admission, security_question, security_answer, admission_year, passing_year, enrollment_no, 
                      first_year_percent, second_year_percent, third_year_percent, final_year_percent, current_degree_percent, year1P, year2P, year3P, year4P, roll_no, 
                      diploma_details
FROM         tbl_students
WHERE     (first_name = 'Rupesh' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) OR
                      (first_name IS NULL)
```

right now i am explicitly checking for first name is null, but i want to know if i set SET ANSI off then can i remove the first_name=null from my query and still i will get the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set ansi nulls off then you can test for null values using first_name = null

As for debugging you can execute the query to see its results in SQLServer Management studio, stored procedures are stored per database under programmability | stored procedures

If you are running a script rather than a single statement you can output to the messages tab of the results pane using the [print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx%22print%22) command

Comment: i have edited my Q may more clear to answer you, previous time you might have miss taken it

Comment: I can see your edit however it still seems to be asking the question I've answered.  Right now your query selects where the first name is either Rupesh or a null value.  If that is what you want setting ansi nulls off will simply mean you test for null in a different way. See here for more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx If you set ansi nulls off and remove the firstname is null clause you will return only where the first name is rupesh.